# WPF ComboBox bind text to selected item

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to bind a `ComboBox` to a collection:

```
<ComboBox  Margin="4 0 2 0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding YAxes}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedYAxis, Mode=TwoWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="AxisTitle"
    SelectedValuePath="AxisTitle"/>
```

Everything is fine, except `Text` of this `ComboBox`. On selection of item, the setter on `SelectedYAxis` fires and notifies, that property has been changed:

```
private IAxis _selectedYAxis;
    public IAxis SelectedYAxis
    {
        get => _selectedYAxis;
        set
        {
            _selectedYAxis = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedYAxis));
        }
    }
```

but the text on `ComboBox` never changes to the selected items `AxisTitle`. How to display an `AxisTitle` of `SelectedItem` as a text of `ComboBox`?

**UPD**: Text is never shown, even if it's set explicitly:

```
<ComboBox  Margin="4 0 2 0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding XAxes}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedXAxis, Mode=TwoWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="AxisTitle"
    Text="Asdasd"/>
```

It doesn't set the text of `ComboBox` to "Asdasd".

**UPD 2**: I've changed the things to use DataTemplate, but this didn't work as well:

```
<ComboBox  Margin="4 0 2 0"
           ItemsSource="{Binding YAxes}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedYAxis, Mode=TwoWay}"
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AxisCBTextTemplate}"/>
```

And the resource section above:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AxisCBTextTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AxisTitle}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**UPD 3**
An illustration to what do I mean:

[image: ComboBox text does never update]

The task of displaying some selected text should be trivial, but it has difficulties.

Comment: To display arbitrary text combobox's `IsEditable` property should be set to `true`

Comment: I hope making your item source YAxes to observable collection may solve this.

Comment: @mohammedmazin nope, it doesn't help

Comment: yours `IAxis` object must override `Equals` to make combobox matches `SelectedItem` in `ItemsSource` list. How do you set the `SelectedYAxis` instance? Is it value from the `YAxes` (in this case SelectedItem should work without custom `Equals`) or loaded from the external source (in this case `object.Equals` does not match your instances for you) ?

Comment: @oleksa `SelectedYAxis` is only set by selection from this `ComboBox`, so it's value is always in `ItemsSource`

Comment: It is not possible, that it doesn't work. Please bind a `TextBlock.Text` to the `ComboBox.Text` property. and you will see that it updates to show the `AxisTitle` value.

Comment: you must not mix `SelectedValuePath="AxisTitle"` with `SelectedItem` please remove the  `SelectedValuePath` and try again. I would like to suggest to start with simplest `<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding YAxes}"   />` and check that combobox text is updated when item is selected

Comment: @oleksa Simple binding to `YAxes` without `ItemTemplate` causes an exception, when combobox is clicked. After addition of `ItemTemplate` no exception is thrown, but text is always empty,
@BionicCode I didn't completely understand, what do you mean.

Comment: @ArliChokoev and what is the exception ?

Comment: @oleksa `NullReferenceException` (though a binded collection is not null) with an `ArgumentException` within: "Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual."

Comment: `ArgumentException` is about some WPF controls movement. I suppose it would be better to create new empty form (view) and try with combobox binding. You do not need to have data template to show combobox items. By default it will use simple text template and will call `.ToString` method to display combobox item text. `NullReference` exception stack should contain class name and line number where error was raised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the root cause of this issue. Each `IAxis` (it is a [SciChart](https://www.scichart.com/) axis object) from `XAxes` and `YAxes` is already dispayed on the graph (i.e. bound). Binding them to other controls (like ListBox) causes an exception: "Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual.", I found it out while trying to bind them to ListBox.

Seemes like ComboBox catches such exceptions and doesn't output StackTrace for any case. In my case this exception was wrapped into `NullReferenceException` and occurred only on click on a ComboBox, that has no `ItemTemplate` set. Though I may not be fully correct in details, replacing `XAxes` and `YAxes` with collections of strings solves this issue.